# RowCount alternative in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to display all tables from a database, which are containing data (not empty). Is the a rowCount function in Teradata, which i could use? Or do i need to do it completely different?

This is my current SQL:

```
SELECT databasename, tablename, CreateTimeStamp, LastAlterTimeStamp
  FROM dbc.tables
 WHERE databasename IN ('db_test') 
   AND tablekind = 'T'
--> [ AND rowcount > 0 ];
```

Comment: The rowcount is not maintained in the DBC tables. You would need to run an aggregate SELECT COUNT(*) query for each table to obtain the current row count. Or you could "snapshot" the count by running COLLECT SUMMARY STATISTICS on each table and then query DBC.StatsV WHERE StatsID=0. BTW - don't use legacy views like dbc.Tables where there is a current alternative with V suffix - dbc.TablesV.

Comment: How should i do run all the statements on each table? It should be dynamic and there are a lot of tables... Also thanks for the dbc.TablesV tip.

Comment: A stored procedure could use a cursor to return the list of table names, then use dynamic SQL to insert counts for each one to a global temporary table instance. Either the SP could return a "dynamic result set" or the caller could query the GTT directly. It's also possible to do a 2-step process on the client side, e.g. using BTEQ - use SQL to create / export count queries and then run the generated SQL.